# Output of making pattern doesn't come as expected?

Tags: java, arrays

> Given an int `n` as input where `n>=0`, create an array with the pattern `{1,1,2,1,2,3,… 1,2,3..n}`.

**My Approach**

I created a pattern which exists and stored that pattern in an array. I am confused here how to specify the size of the array. But when I managed to remove certain extra 0s I get null output

```
public int[] create(int num) {
    int k=0;
    int x[]=new int[10];   //I was confused here how much size? 
    for(int i=1;i<=num;i++) {
        for(int j=1;j<i+1;j++) {
            x[k++]=j;
        }  
    }    
    return x;  
}
```

To remove zeros I wrote the following code.

```
int g=0;
for(int i=0;x[i]!=0;i++) {
    count++;
}
x=new int[count];
for(int p=1;p<=num;p++) {
    for(int q=1;q<p+1;q++) {
        x[g++]=q;
    }  
}
```

**My Question:** I am not getting expected output. Should I create a new array for this?

```
Parameters       Actual Output           Expected Output

'3'               {1,1,2,1,2,3,0,0,0,0} {1,1,2,1,2,3}
```

Comment: If you want to make an array smaller, the only way is to make a new array of the size you want. [`Arrays.copyOf(original, newSize)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int[],%20int%29) will do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to calculate the size of the resulting array:

```
{1,1,2,1,2,3,...,1,2,3,..,n}
```

So there's `n` elements at the end (`1,2,3,..,n`) preceded by `n-1` elements (`1,2,3,..,n-1`), etc, until there is a single element. So the total count of elements is `n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1`, [which is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) `n*(n+1)/2`.

Now let's try to come up with a simple algorithm to generate the wanted array. As we can see, the array is made of `n` subarrays where the first is `{1}`, the second in `{1,2}`, ..., and the last is `{1,2,...,n}`:

- For each value going from 0 to `n` excluded (this will correspond to the `n` subarrays)
- We need to populate an array of values going from 1 to `n`.

Sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 3;

    int[] result = new int[n*(n+1)/2];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            result[index++] = j + 1;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```